# How do we show the vector $v = (0,1,1)$ belongs (or not) to the space spanned by $w = (1,1,-1)$ and $z = (1,0,2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have found the range to be these to vectors [1,1,-1] and [1,0,2]

How do I show/find out if this vector [0,1,1] belong to that range?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, I have tried row reduction. to set up a matrix and performed row operation. Then I get the reduced row echelon form, and this shows that the tree vectors are linearly independent.. But I don't know if it is the right method or how to interpret the result..

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Consider the following linear combination
\begin{align*}
(0,1,1) = \alpha(1,1,-1) + \beta(1,0,2) = (\alpha + \beta,\alpha,-\alpha + 2\beta)
\end{align*}

Does the corresponding system of equations have a solution?